# A Simple Alternative to Geometry for Changing textwidth within a Document for a Single Page Only

Tags: minipage, geometry, textwidth, textheight

The following code produces three pages of output, wherein the `textwidth` of each page is 6 inches.

```
\documentclass{book}
\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight 25pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9in \textwidth 6in
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2] % Would like textwidth to be 4in
\newpage
\lipsum[2] % Would like the textwidth to revert back to 6in.
\end{document}
```

I would like to temporarily change the `textwidth` of the document (second page only) to say, 4 inches.

I know this can be done rather easily with the `geometry` package but it seems to slightly affect the display of the output. I suppose, also, that `minipage` might work as long as there is no overflow at the end of the page.

QUESTION: Is there a way (and if so, how) to change the `textwidth` of the output for one page only without resorting to either the `geometry` package or a `minipage` environment? Also, although I don't need it at the moment, if the approach could also accommodate a temporary `textheight` change, that would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: minipage or something simple like the `quote`  environment which simply changes the margins. You can not change the geometry of a page without severely restricting page breaking as it is _very_ hard to change the text width mid-paragraph which is needed if you allow the page to end mid paragraph.  `geometry` is overkill for this unless you need to change the external page geometry so that your pdf viewer shows a different shape page for that page rather than just changing margins within the page.

Comment: changing textheight is easy (and provided by default with `\enlargethispage{2cm}` changing `\textwidth` is not possible in general.

Comment: @Divid Carlisle Thank you for your comments. So, regarding `textwidth`, it sounds as if `geometry` or `minipage` (or `quote`) are my only options. I didn't realize I could get `quote` to extend beyond the specified width. If I recall correctly, it always for me produced a length less than textwidth.  Thank you again.

Comment: well `quote` does but its definition is only one line so you can make a similar enviornment that  increases rather than decreases or there is a change width environment that takes the new width as an argument.  or just put `{\hsize=4in  words here <blank line>}` you don't really need anything at all.

Comment: Thank you. @David Carlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this extension to your MWE.

```
% onepageprob.tex  SE 629962

\documentclass{book}
\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight 25pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9in \textwidth 6in
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\changetextwidth}[1]{\twocolumn \setlength{\textwidth}{#1} \onecolumn}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lipsum[1]
%\newpage
\twocolumn
\setlength{\textwidth}{4in}
\onecolumn
\lipsum[2] % Would like textwidth to be 4in
%\newpage
\twocolumn
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
\onecolumn
\lipsum[2] % Would like the textwidth to revert back to 6in.

START AGAIN

\newpage

\lipsum[1]
\changetextwidth{4in}
\lipsum[2] % Would like textwidth to be 4in
\changetextwidth{6in}
\lipsum[2] % Would like the textwidth to revert back to 6in.

\end{document}
```

It is based on my perhaps poor recollection of something from Donald Arseneau at least 3 decades ago. When LaTeX changes between one and two columns it starts a new page and reconfigures the page layout. I just did the column swapping in the body of the MWE as in the first part above which shows what is going on. Then thought that it could be done via a macro, namely my `\changetextwidth` which is used in the second part of the MWE.

**AN EXTENDED ANSWER**

My initial answer was based on the OP's MWE where the document started as a `onecolumn` document. However I eventually realised the a document could start in `twocolumn` mode. To cater for this my original `\changetextwidth` macro should be changed, as below, to take account of the current one/two column status.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changetextwidth}[1]{
  \if@twocolumn%
    \onecolumn \setlength{\textwidth}{#1} \twocolumn
  \else
    \twocolumn \setlength{\textwidth}{#1} \onecolumn
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you again for posting this answer. I tried running it on my document without either `\twocolumn` or `\onecolumn` and it seemed to work OK. Are such actually needed here? It's not clear to me why they are being used here. Many thanks.

Comment: @mlchristians I don't understand what you have done. If I delete the `twocolumn` and `onecolumn` from my `\changetextwidth` macro as used after START AGAIN in my MWE then nothing happens.

Comment: When I ran a very short version of your answer (producing a 3-page output, I recall), it didn't seem to matter if I included the commands `\onecolumn` or `\twocolumn`.  However, when I (just now) ran your answer as is both with and without these commands, it does seem to matter. Perhaps you would kindly (briefly) explain what these commands are and why they are needed---as the MWE I posted does not have multiple columns. Thank you,

Comment: @mlchristians I'm apologise for my answer not being clear enough for you. Forget the `onecolumn/twocolumn ` option to the `\documentclass`. When LaTeX sees a `\onecolumn or \twocolumn` command it starts a new page and recalculates the page layout. My extended answer is meant to deal with the `\documentclass` `onecoumn/twocolumn` option.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me. I just wanted to understand it better. Thank you again.